# How to increase speed of downloading files from ftp server apache

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client

I have an apache server implemented running in one host, and apache ftp client on the other.
When running download from the client code, i see that after downloading around 150 MB the download speed dramatically decreased.

**Note: I'm trying to download more than 2 GB**

I have tried downloading the same folder using filezila on the same machine where the ftp client is runnig and in this scenario the download rate was much faster.

so i guess i have a problem with mu implementatio of the FTP Client.

any ide?

**below my code for FTPClient download impl:**

```
try (BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos,
                        ftpConfig.getBufferOutputStreamSize()))
                {
                    InputStream inputStream = client.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[bufferSize]; 
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1)
                    {
                        bufferedOutputStream.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    result = client.completePendingCommand();
                    inputStream.close();
                    bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                    fos.flush();
                }
            }
```

I have noticed the following exception in the client log:

```
   Exception of the class java.net.SocketTimeoutException
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |           java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:127)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:182)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:144)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/12/06 11:42:39 |   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:118)
```

Comment: So what's your real buffer size? Remove the `ftpConfig` references and show us real values!

Comment: Buffer size i'm using is 1024

Comment: So the `ftpConfig.getBufferOutputStreamSize()` that goes to `BufferedOutputStream` is 1024?

Comment: @martinPrikryl yes! it's configured to 1024 in realtime

Comment: 1024 is not a buffer. That's even less that buffer of an OS, so 1024 has no effect at all. Use at least 10240, or even more.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have increased to 20480 and it seems to be much slower...even more than it used to be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160599/discussion-between-user4860092-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: Did you increase the `BufferedOutputStream` buffer or `bufferSize` or both? Did you try removing the writing part and keeping the `inputStream.read` only?

Comment: I have changed for both the client configuration and the bufferedOutPutStream. can we continue in the private chat i have opened?https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160599/discussion-between-user4860092-and-martin-prikryl